# gcc platform tuning option with backward compatibility

Tags: linux, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization, avx

I'm looking for the GCC option (if exists) to automatically optimize my code for modern Intel architectures like AVX or later.

As I understand GCC has `-march=core-avx2` compilation option but it generates the code that can not be run on previous architectures.

As I know, Intel compiler has `-axAVX` (note letter 'a' before -xarch) compilation option that generates function versioning in the places where special optimization for AVX were made.

This allow the compiled binary works on modern architecture faster (with AVX extension) and keep compatibility with previous architectures.
Could you please recommend me GCC compiler option to be similar to Intel compiler `-axAVX`?

I see the solution with `__attribute__(target_clones ...)` but this is not acceptable due to requires lot of code changes.

OS: Linux

Compiler: gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC)

Comment: There is ifunc in modern linux: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html to create and select several variants of functions; some may be compiled with AVX, other with SSE2.

Comment: There is `-mtune=` but I don't think that does new instructions, only chooses between instruction schedulings.

Comment: Possibly you could automate `__attribute__((target_clones))` by compiling *two* copies of every object file, and then doing some ELF magic.

Comment: Actually, if you can afford to operate at the shared-library granularity, `ld-linux.so` has builtin support for "hardware capabilities" ... though it doesn't appear to define any for recent architectures.